# Passing Select Value through Javascript/Jquery/AJAX to php varibale

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a code, where when i select a value through Drop-down, the name I am selecting should pass through a PHP variable $ch so a second drop-down which runs a mysql query.

Here is my code for first dropdown:

```
<select name="cha_name" id="cha_name" onChange="fillcha(this.value);">
        <option value="0">--SELECT--</option>
        <?php
            $res = mysqli_query($con, "select customer_code, customer from master_customer where is_cha = 1 order by customer") or die(mysqli_error($con));
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                echo "<option value=\"".$row[1]."$$".$row[0]."\" ".(($row[1]==$wo_order[1])?"selected='selected'":"").">".$row[1]."</option>";
            }
        ?>

      </select>
```

When i select this, the value should be capture in a PHP variable $ch without reloading the page show the PHP variable can be used further in a mysql query. Kindly help as I am still in learning phase for JQuery and Ajax.

the mysql query is as follows:

```
SELECT container_no FROM  `cex_work_order_det` WHERE `cha_name`='$cha'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5861207/4229270

Comment: Try this : SELECT container_no FROM  `cex_work_order_det` WHERE `cha_name`= "$cha"

Answer (score 1):

for that you have to use jquery and ajax
 jquery code

```
 <script>
  $("document").ready(function()
  {
  $("select[name='cha_name']").change(function() // function sorting Domain according to server name 
   {
      var customer_code=$("select[name='cha_name']").val();
         $.get('ajax_actions.php?act=your-act-name&customer_code='+customer_code,function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        });
   });
   });
 </script>
```

ajax_actions.php

```
<?php
 error_reporting(0);
 foreach ($_GET as $name => $value) { $$name = $value; }
 foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) { $$name = $value; }

// warning Dont chnage anything  in This ajax action file 
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if($act=="your-act-name")  // do your actions

{ 
  // fire here your query  and echo you result here
}
```

Comment: does the action mean i should write my mysql query?

Comment: ya fire query and echo query result if your query returs multiple records then use JSON_encode